# inner join one field to multiple columns in table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have SQL table that holds buyers personal data such as FirstName, LastName, OGCard;
OGCard - field that indicates clients personal card number.

Next I have table called Cards which contains data about ten items that were purchased in the following format: OGCard, Item1ID,...,Item10ID,Item1Quantity,...,Item10Quantity

And in table Items I got such structure ItemID, ItemName

I want to get all purchases from CardNumber

I think i should do something like that

```
SELECT Buyers.FirstName, Items.Name, Cards.Item1Quantity
FROM Buyers
INNER JOIN Cards ON Buyers.OGCard=Cards.OGCard
INNER JOIN Items ON Cards.Item1ID=Items.ItemName
WHERE OGCard=13451
```

In this way I can see the name of first item and it's quantity. However i cannot perform the same join to column Item2ID, and so on. Could you suggest me some solution?

Comment: Can you redesign your database? Having columns named foo1, foo2, ..., foo10 is nearly always a bad idea.

Comment: I really need to have such tables structure for normalization purposes

Comment: It's not normalized. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form "Repeating groups across columns".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to join the same table twice by using aliases:

```
SELECT
    Buyers.FirstName,
    Items1.Name, Cards.Item1Quantity,
    Items2.Name, Cards.Item2Quantity,
    Items3.Name, Cards.Item3Quantity,
    Items4.Name, Cards.Item4Quantity
FROM Buyers
INNER JOIN Cards ON Buyers.OGCard=Cards.OGCard
INNER JOIN Items AS Items1 ON Cards.Item1ID=Items.ItemName
INNER JOIN Items AS Items2 ON Cards.Item2ID=Items.ItemName
INNER JOIN Items AS Items3 ON Cards.Item3ID=Items.ItemName
INNER JOIN Items AS Items4 ON Cards.Item4ID=Items.ItemName
WHERE OGCard=13451
```

If some of the `Items_n_ID`s can be missing, you could use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` so that you still get the results for the values that are present.

However I'd strongly recommend you to normalize your database rather than going with this approach.

Answer (score 6):

Without knowing how the Items table is set up you could do:

```
SELECT Buyers.FirstName
     , Items.Name
     , Cards.Item1Quantity 
     , C2.Item2Quantity
     , C3.Item3Quantity
     , C4.Item4Quantity
     , C5.Item5Quantity
     , C6.Item6Quantity
     , C7.Item7Quantity
     , C8.Item8Quantity
     , C9.Item9Quantity
     , C10.Item10Quantity 
  FROM Buyers 
 INNER JOIN Cards ON Buyers.OGCard=Cards.OGCard 
 INNER JOIN Items ON Cards.Item1ID=Items.ItemName  
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Items ON Cards.Item2D=Items.ItemName C2
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Items ON Cards.Item3D=Items.ItemName C3
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Items ON Cards.Item4D=Items.ItemName C4
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Items ON Cards.Item5D=Items.ItemName C5
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Items ON Cards.Item6D=Items.ItemName C6
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Items ON Cards.Item7D=Items.ItemName C7
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Items ON Cards.Item8D=Items.ItemName C8
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Items ON Cards.Item9D=Items.ItemName C9
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Items ON Cards.Item10D=Items.ItemName C10
 WHERE OGCard=13451
```

Without the table layouts this is just a guess and I would guess if this works you need to look at how the schema is layed out...